# How i can extract the data from btrieve files?

Tags: btrieve

I have .btr files, i need to extract the data from these files. I don't have the definition files. which tool can help me extract the data ?

Answer (score 1):

Btrieve files do not have field metadata stored in them.  It is up to the developer to know the record layout.
If you have Data Definition Files (DDFs), you could use ODBC to extract the data.
If you don't have DDFs, can you get them from the vendor or do you know the record layout for the file(s)?  If you can't get the DDFs or the layout, you'll be limited to the application to export data.
If you know the record structure, you should be able to create DDFs. 
You *might* be able to determine the record layout by putting in specific, unique values for each field and then using that record to determine the layout.
You will need a Btrieve engine that can read the files.  There is no way to get the data out without the Btrieve engine.

Comment: I have already installed Pervasive PSQL, but i still cant get the data from my .btr files as i don't have the .ddf files.

Comment: As stated above, you need to know the record layout of the files and then you can create DDFs.  If you don't have the record layout, you should contact the vendor of the program you are using to find out if they offer DDFs or the layout.